# How to display pivot table without any calculations

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have 2 columns of data in excel as below

**Country Region**
  USA     North
  Canada  North
  Brasil  South
  Mexico  South

I would like it to display as such

**North   South**
  USA     Brasil

Canada  Mexico

Comment: Use index match...

Answer (score 0):

I have two suggestions for this.

The first won't get you the exact display you're inquiring about, but it's much simpler, doesn't require calculations and it also uses a pivot table.  You will be using region as a filter and will get either North or South.

**Method #1:**

1. Select the two columns country and region
2. On the top, click on Insert
3. The first choice is PivotTable, click that
4. Confirm the information is correct and hit OK

[Visual of Steps 1-4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BgtYt.png)

5. Using the PivotTable Builder, drag Region into filters and Country into rows
6. On the Excel spreadsheet, the first row will say Region (All).  Click the drop down on (All) and select either North or South

[Visual of Step 6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FAmg.png)

**Method #2 (involves a calculation):**

- You're going to use a series of Excel functions - if(), iserror(), index(), small(), and row()
- Feel free to change E1 to North or South
- [Reference](http://eimagine.com/how-to-return-multiple-match-values-in-excel-using-index-match-or-vlookup/)

[Visual of Excel Spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67NGE.png)

Formula for the first entry:

```
=IF(ISERROR(INDEX($A$1:$B$5,SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$5=$E$1,ROW($A$1:$A$5)),ROW($A$1:$A$2)),2)),"",INDEX($A$1:$B$5,SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$5=$E$1,ROW($A$1:$A$5)),ROW($A$1:$A$2)),2))
```

Formula for the second entry:

```
=IF(ISERROR(INDEX($A$1:$B$5,SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$5=$E$1,ROW($A$1:$A$5)),ROW($A$2:$A$3)),2)),"",INDEX($A$1:$B$5,SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$5=$E$1,ROW($A$1:$A$5)),ROW($A$2:$A$3)),2))
```

*Note:* Remember to hit CONTROL + SHIFT + ENTER because it's an array formula